# Bootstrap Nav Button Not Working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Have a couple of issues with my code. Firstly I can't figure out why my navigation button is not working when the screen is resized. Also I noticed the navigation drops below the heading and tagline as the screen gets smaller. How do I make the button appear before the navigation drops down? Also when the navigation button appears the heading and tagline do not center align between the logo and `nav` button. Here is a link to codepen. If someone can explain how to fix these issues it would be greatly appreciated.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPjWvw

Comment: change your `data-target="#main-nav"` to `data-target="#navigation" `

Answer (score 0):

your data-target is wrong.

data-target="target menu list id" here your menu list id is "navigation" and what you put is "main-nav".

```
<button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#main-nav" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
```

change to

```
<button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#navigation" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
```